# undefined local variable or method `locked_at' for #<User:0x007f28a2101568> Did you mean? lock_access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I have made a project in ruby on rails for authentication using devise and facebook. While logging in through devise simple sign up I am getting this error of:

> undefined local variable or method `locked_at' for # Did you mean? lock_access!

[image]

Comment: Does your users table have locked_at field?

Comment: Please take a look at [`https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`](How do I ask a good question?). **Some suggestions:** Change the title of your post to describe the problem. Include the code where the error is being thrown. Try not to use screenshots for posting errors/code--it's better when the text is easily copied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think locked_at column were not added for users table

generate migration for adding column in users table

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :locked_at, :datetime
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who are coming here from Google like me, you may want to also heed this line in the Devise getting started README - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

> Next, check the MODEL for any additional configuration options you
>   might want to add, such as confirmable or lockable. If you add an
>   option, be sure to inspect the migration file (created by the
>   generator if your ORM supports them) and uncomment the appropriate
>   section. For example, if you add the confirmable option in the model,
>   you'll need to uncomment the Confirmable section in the migration.

Double check your Devise users migration file (`db/migrate/TIMESTAMP_devise_create_users.rb`) and uncomment any of the necessary sections. In this case, the sections relating to the `Lockable` module.